# "Press 1 at any time" in Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm trying to make a Twilio workflow that allows for a user to press 1 at any time to cancel out (as long as a `<Dial>` hasn't connected yet) and leave a voicemail instead. The TwiML documentation offers a `<Gather>` option, but this is for a specific time and it supposedly won't let me run a `<Dial>` command during a `<Gather>`. Is there a trick to getting this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

You should be able to Dial another number after gathering input.

`<Gather action="[your_gather_processing_url]">`

When the `<Gather>` completes (eg the user presses one), then Twilio will make a request for the URL you've set in the action parameter.  In there you can use `<Dial>` to connect to another number.

It sounds like what you want to do is have Twilio `<Gather>` for input *while* the `<Dial>` is  ringing.  I believe in that case you are correct, thats something we cannot do today.

One option might be to use `<Dial>`s [timeout](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-timeout) property to set a finite limit on the length of time Twilio will wait for the call to be answered (its 30 seconds by default), and then in the action URL, check the [DialCallStatus](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action-parameters) to see if the call was not-answered and send to voicemail when appropriate.

Hope that helps.